# Correct version of "Space Bar"

Tags: orthography, technical

Is it acceptable to spell it "spacebar" or must the word be spelled with a space in it? I'm using it to refer to a keyboard shortcut in my application's documentation.

Further, should it be capitalized? And if split into two words, should both be capitalized?

Comment: Yikes! "spacebar" always, please.

Comment: [Space Bar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSRwzP23ifI).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely not capitalized: a Space Bar would be something like a Mars Bar or Milky Way, but less dense (facetious confectionery reference).

But whether you include a space is up to you.  Originally so: *the space bar* is just below *the X key*, which requires a space to avoid confusion.  However, spacebar is common enough not to be ambiguous by now.

Comment: [This](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=spacebar%2Cspace+bar&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) NGram suggests the single-word version really took over in the 90s, when the referent itself became common enough for 'ordinary' people to need the word. Leafing through a few dozen, it looks to me as if 5-10% are pointlessly capitalised. But I'd expect that to diminish over time, since it's largely a "techie" style (we even use *SpaceBar* sometimes! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the 4th edition of the Microsoft Manual of Style, *Spacebar* should be capitalized, similar to the other keys on the keyboard.

Several general language dictionaries reference the word without capitalization, written as two words (cf. [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/space-bar?q=space%20bar), [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/space%20bar)).

To make matters more confusing, [Microsoft's Terminology Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/language/Search?&searchTerm=spacebar&langID=Fran%C3%A7ais&Source=false&productid=Tous%20les%20produits) proposes several different variants: *SPACEBAR*, *Spacebar*, and *spacebar*.

A search in Google Books provides yet more examples illustrating why we're all asking ourselves this question; *SPACEBAR*, *Spacebar*, *space bar*, and *spacebar* are all found in publication.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

All the keys on a keyboard are written with capital letters, so logic suggests it's written as "Spacebar".

Comment: Do you have sources? As it is now, I disagree with you.

Comment: The identification marks on the keys are written with capital letters, but my spacebar doesn't have anything written on it.